# Office 365 A1 Plus for faculty, what will happen to files in local OneDrive folder when license ends

Tags: sync, office365, onedrive, license, cloud-storage

I have Office 365 A1 Plus for faculty.

As part of this license, I have 1 TB of storage in OneDrive that I can sync to my Windows 10 personal computer. At some point, the school that I teach for will be realigning the faculty and I may no longer have any classes to teach.

When the school ends my subscription to Office 365 A1 Plus for faculty, what will happen to the files that I have in the OneDrive folder on my personal computer? Will they all be deleted?

I'd rather not back them up somewhere else right now because that would be another TB of space. So, if my subscription ends and OneDrive syncs and removes all of the files in the OneDrive folder on my personal computer, I would lose all of those files.

My question: is it possible that OneDrive would remove files from the local OneDrive folder when a license or subscription ends?

Here are more details about the license that I have:

Office 365 A1 Plus for faculty

```
• Office 365 A1 Plus for faculty
• Microsoft Kaizala Pro
• Whiteboard (Plan 1)
• To-Do (Plan 2)
• Azure Active Directory Basic for EDU
• School Data Sync (Plan 1)
• Microsoft Stream for O365 E3 SKU
• Microsoft Teams
• Microsoft StaffHub
• Flow for Office 365
• PowerApps for Office 365
• Azure Rights Management
• Microsoft Forms (Plan 2)
• Microsoft Planner
• Sway
• Yammer for Academic
• The latest desktop version of Office
• Office for the web (Education)
• SharePoint Plan 1 for EDU
• Exchange Online (Plan 1)
```

Comment: This is a question for your Microsoft rep.

Comment: Do you know how I would reach out to the Microsoft rep? It seems like I can't obtain any help myself and the IT of our school has to work with them. But maybe I just don't know how to ask them.

Comment: No, we aren't Microsoft. Also, your school IT probably knows this information. Why haven't you asked them?

Comment: Thank you, I recognize you're not Microsoft, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with these enterprise-level software licenses and how support is obtained. I haven't asked IT because they have struggled in the past with very simple issues and I thought this wasn't a novice question. Fair enough, I could try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your account is disabled, you can stop syncing to your local drive. Then the account can be removed from your employer's tenant and your local files will not be affected.

To do that, right-click on the blue cloud icon in the system tray, then select Settings. In the dialog that pops up, select "Stop sync".

At the top of the dialog, you can then also unlink the PC from the OneDrive cloud storage by clicking "Unlink this PC".

Now the files will remain on your hard drive even if they are deleted at the tenant.

Edit: unless the files get deleted on the server and then your account syncs with your local machine, you should still have a local copy.

Please note: While you are still syncing files, your employer can apply settings to your files that would require you to have a valid account in order to access them, or to expire the files on your hard drive. These tools fall under the information rights management.

Comment: Thank you, this helps, but my question might be better stated, would my local files be affected if I don't unlink my PC before my account is disabled? I don't know exactly when my account will be disabled.

Comment: I edited my answer.